# How to add more than one test object from testobject map to the script

Tags: automated-tests, bulk

Test which I have to automate: In an applicationmy I have to create 1000 objects. Then I have to go to each object and I have to put some value.

Using script I created one object and then going to this object and putting value.

Now in object creation step I put a for loop which created 1000 objects of different name.

Now using "Add Object to test map object" wizard of RFT I added all these objects to test object map.

Now I want to add all these objects from test object map to my script. With RFT tool I can add one by one which is time consuming. I want a method by which I could select all these object from test object map and add to script.

If you know then please provide me solution. For this I will be thankfull to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the object definitions in a different form of repository to the native Object Map provided by RFT. Then you could use the [TestObject.find](http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0711_nowacki_nodwell/) method to locate the objects dynamically.